# How to check if key pressed when clicked event in java

Tags: java, event-handling, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I want to catch the Clicked event in java when key pressed (not ctrl, or shift, or alt), or check if key "A" press druing key "D" pressed. How can i do that, something like the method isshiftdown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a mouse listener like this:

```
component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    mouseDown = true;
  }
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    mouseDown = false;
  }
});
```

and the key listener:

```
component.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(mouseDown){
      System.out.println("the key was pressed while the mouse is down.");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants the action to be the other way. like Key was pressed first and then a mouse click happened.

Comment: was hard to tell due to his english

Comment: Also, referring to the same variable in two different classes is difficult too unless its final I guess... So it may not be feasible to implement this.

Comment: how do you know it's two different classes?

Comment: How can u declare mouseDown what u can use Design Mode (WindowBuilder in Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by making an array of booleans and when the key is pressed set that key's boolean to true and when not pressed set it to false.

```
public boolean[] key = new boolean[68836];
```

Dont ask me why it is 68836...
Your class would look something like this:

```
public class keyHandler implements KeyListener, MouseListener{

int KeyCode = 0;
Main main;

    public KeyHandler(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode > 0 && keyCode < key.length) {
            main.key[keyCode] = true;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode > 0 && keyCode < key.length) {
            main.key[keyCode] = false;
        }
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        main.MouseButton = e.getButton();
        main.MousePressed true;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        main.MouseButton = 0;
        main.MousePressed = false;
    }
}
```

Next you would have some kind of loop class to allow you to check the booleans regularly:

```
public class Time extends Thread{
    Main main;
    public Time(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            main.update();// you would probably want some timing system here
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main class or something:

```
public class Main {
//whatever you have here
public boolean[] key = new boolean[68836];
int MouseButton = 0;
boolean MousePressed = false;

    public Main(){
        Component c; //whatever you are using e.g JFrame
        //whatever you do to your component
        KeyHandler kh = new KeyHandler(this);
        c.addKeyListener(kh);
        c.addMouseListener(kh);
    }

    public void update(){
        if(key[KeyEvent.VK_A] && key[KeyEvent.VK_D){
            //both keys are pressed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you wanted. you can use some stuff from java.awt.event package called KeyEvent.

Here is a complete example:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/KeyEventDemoProject/src/events/KeyEventDemo.java

copy it to your own IDE and give it a run

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is have a Boolean array to store the currently pressed keys, and then use other methods to access them when needed. For example...

```
Boolean[] keys = new Boolean[256];
Boolean mousePressed = false;
...
keyPressed(MouseEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}
...
keyReleased (MouseEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}
....
mousePressed (MouseEvent e) { mousePressed=true; }
```

Then whenever you need to see it a combination of keys was pressed, just reference the array and see if that key is currently true. It works equally well for both mouse and key listeners.